# How to know if iPhone was used

Tags: iphone, unlock, history

I need to know if someone has used my iPhone or not. Sometimes I can't recall the last time I used my iPhone and I've tried many things to view the log if that is even possible.

Is there a "Slide to unlock" history log maintained on iPhone? Or any other way to determine times when the iPhone was used?

Comment: Best way to know if someone used your phone or not is to not let anyone else know the passcode, then you know the answer is 'no'.

Comment: @unknown let us know what response helped you most and what you might have done to fix your issue by pressing "comment" under the appropriate answer, then accept answer you like most with the checkmark symbol.

Answer (score 2):

Set a passcode on the device.  End of problem.

Answer (score 1):

With the iPhone or Android app [Checky](http://www.checkyapp.com/), you can record when your iPhone or Android Phone was unlocked.